# How to deploy next.js webapp with firebase multi site hosting?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, next.js

i tried to deploy a next.js app using firebase multi site hosting but i am not able to understand what the folder structure will be and how it's done so anybody can help ??
Till this i have created a src folder in which there is a public folder , a functions folder and apps folder in apps there are two folders admin and customer so how can i do this thing. Please suggest Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can either have separate a Firebase Hosting configuration for each site, so you'll have a `firebase.json` for each of your `public`, `admin`, and `customers` sites/folders, or you can combine them into a single `firebase.json`.

In the case of the latter, you'd define the `firebase.json` at the top-level of your project as something like this:

```
{
  "hosting": [ {
      "target": "public",
      "public": "src"

      // ...

      "rewrites": [...] // You can define specific hosting configurations for each site
    },
    {
      "target": "admin", // "app" is the applied target-name for the Hosting site myapp-app
      "public": "app/admin",
    },
    {
      "target": "customers",
      "public": "app/customers",
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then deploy all sites with `firebase deploy`, or deploy a specific site with `firebase deploy --only hosting:admin`.

See [define the hosting configuration for each site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#define_hosting_config).